# Finding min and max value given region in first quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the greatest and lowest value of $f(x,y) = e^{2xy}$ over the region **R** in the first quadrant enclosed by the lines $y = 4x$ and $x = 4y$ and the curves $xy = 2$ and $ xy = 7$.

Im guessing the lowest value must be when $x,y = 0.$ Since the region is so complex i don't know how to go about finding the maximum value.

Comment: If I read your description of the region correctly, the point $x=y=0$ does not belong to region $\mathbf R$.  Perhaps you should draw a picture to get a better feel for the boundaries of that region.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just made a mistake thinking $x = y = 0$ was in the region. All i did was restate exactly what the problem said. I didn't make up the description of the region myself.

Comment: I understand that the problem is exactly as you stated it (defining the region), but before posting a vebatim statement of the problem, you should give it enough thought to digest what the lines and curves do in creating a bounded region.  Then you will be able to setup the problem for Readers in a way that gives a better idea of where you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No work necessary here - since $\exp(\cdot)$ is an increasing function, you are seeking to maximize and minimize $xy$ over the interval in question, to the minima of $e^4$ occur when $xy=2$ and the maxima of $e^{14}$ when $xy=7$.

Comment: what about the $y=4x$ and $x=4y$? You present lower and upper bounds, but your answer is not definitive.

Comment: @LinAlg it is definitive -- as long as there is at least one point on either line